# Hunchentoot List of Redirects

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

The URI structure of my website changed drastically recently and I need to redirect all of the old pages to their corresponding new pages. I have a dotted list of pairs of all of the old and new URIs. At the moment I am trying to define easy handlers for each in a loop:

```
(let ((redirects '(("/old/uri/example-1" . "/new/uri/example-1"))))
  (dolist (redirect redirects)
    (hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (???? :uri (first redirect)) ()
       (redirect (rest redirect)))
    ))
```

Maybe there is a better way. Assuming define-easy-handler is correct, it requires a function symbol for each easy handler. I tried the following to no avail:

1. Placing a (gensym) where it expects a function symbol
2. Using lists rather than dotted lists and calling (first redirect) where it expects a symbol
3. Placing a quasiquote around the whole thing and an unquote around (first redirect)

What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to consider creating a [custom acceptor](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#acceptor-behaviour) instead of using easy handlers. That way you can do the redirects whatever way you want.

Comment: Thanks @jkiiski. Your suggestion seems like a better way to solve it than the way I did. I aspire to gain enough skill to implement such a solution some day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's guess: `DEFINE-EASY-HANDLER` is a macro.

Three typical ways to solve that:

- call the underlying layer instead and don't use the macro - if the underlying layer is available for the programmer
- write and use a macro which

expands `(defredirects (a . a1) (b . b1) (c . c1)))` into

```
(progn
  (hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (f-a ... a) () (... a1))
  (hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (f-b ... b) () (... b1))
  (hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (f-c ... c) () (... c1)))
```

- Generate the form you want to call and use `eval` (or `compile` and `funcall` if possible) in the loop for each form.

Comment: Thank you for your list of available options. See my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Although you already solved the problem I figured I might add this as an alternative. If you don't want to make a whole custom acceptor, you can add an around-method on `HUNCHENTOOT:ACCEPTOR-DISPATCH-REQUEST` for `HUNCHENTOOT:EASY-HANDLER`.

Let's make an acceptor and one page first:

```
(defparameter *acceptor* (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 4242))

(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (foo :uri "/foo") ()
  (format nil "<html><body><h1>Test</h1><p>foo</p></body></html>"))

(hunchentoot:start *acceptor*)
```

Then redirect `/bar` and `/quux` to `/foo`:

```
;; A simple helper to create prefix dispatchers.
(defun make-redirect-list (redirects)
  (mapcar (lambda (redirect)
            (destructuring-bind (from . to) redirect
              (hunchentoot:create-prefix-dispatcher from
                                                    (lambda ()
                                                      (hunchentoot:redirect to)))))
          redirects))

(defparameter *redirects* (make-redirect-list
                           '(("/bar" . "/foo")
                             ("/quux" . "/foo"))))

(defmethod hunchentoot:acceptor-dispatch-request :around
    ((acceptor hunchentoot:easy-acceptor) request)
  (dolist (redirect *redirects*)
    ;; Match the request against the prefix dispatchers in *REDIRECTS*...
    (let ((handler (funcall redirect request)))
      (when handler
        ;; and call the corresponding handler if a match is found.
        (return-from hunchentoot:acceptor-dispatch-request
          (funcall handler)))))
    ;; Unless a handler was found, call next method to 
    ;; handle the request normally.
  (call-next-method))
```

Edit: Use around method instead of before. I initially figured that letting it call the main method normally would be necessary for any logging/etc. happening there, but after further testing it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Awesome. I follow your code up until the CLOS part. It is apparent that this solution is better than mine. It uses lambdas to avoid cluttering the namespace rather than creating individual functions for each of the redirects. It also avoids using eval and quasiquote to coerce Lisp into using variable function names.

Comment: @SpyroSoft I changed the code to use an around-method instead of a before-method. `ACCEPTOR-DISPATCH-REQUEST` is the method that hunchentoot acceptors use to figure out what to do with requests. Defining an around-method for it basically means that this method will be called first every time it is called. Since this is an around-method, `CALL-NEXT-METHOD` is needed to call the actual main-method defined by hunchentoot (before-methods would call it automatically). Of course if one of the redirects matches the request, `RETURN-FROM` is used to return early without calling the main-method.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works. I definitely appreciate feedback regarding whether or not it's best practice.

```
(defun add-redirect (name from to)
  (eval `(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (,name :uri ,from) ()
    (redirect ,to))))

(defun add-redirects (redirects)
  (dolist (redirect redirects)
    (add-redirect (first redirect) (second redirect) (third redirect))
    ))

(add-redirects
 '(
   (redirect-1 "/redirect-1/" "/destination-1/")
   (redirect-2 "/redirect-2/" "/destination-2/")
   (redirect-3 "/redirect-3/" "/destination-3/")
   ))
```

Comment: It turns out that what was throwing me off was the function definition itself. I was getting the error "Not legal as a function name:" when I tried to use a symbol. I'm not sure how to produce a function symbol? I'm not even sure that is the correct terminology.