# hunchentoot around method to redirect with post parameters

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I'm trying to code a login page, where:

- the user will fill a form with post method
- if the form has a target url starting with "/auth-", the user will be redirected to the "/login" page
- the user will fill username and password, etc
- if authorization is granted, all information will be, say, inserted to the database
- if username or password is false, all information will be retained for a second chance

The intention is not much different than [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577011/redirect-with-post-parameters-in-mvc-4-for-payment-gateway-integration), if my aim is not clear yet.

This around method inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534244/hunchentoot-list-of-redirects) allows me to redirect any link starting with "auth-" to redirect to a login page, along with the get parameters:

```
(defmethod hunchentoot:acceptor-dispatch-request :around
    ((acceptor hunchentoot:easy-acceptor) request)
  (let* ((address-bar (cl-ppcre:split "\\?" (hunchentoot:request-uri* request)))
         (just-url (first address-bar))
         (query-params (second address-bar)))
    (if (cl-ppcre:scan "^/auth-" just-url)
      (hunchentoot:redirect (if query-params
                (format nil "/login?~A" query-params)
                "/login"))
      (call-next-method))))
```

But how can I redirect with post parameters instead?

I thought sth along the lines:

```
(defmethod hunchentoot:acceptor-dispatch-request :around
    ((acceptor hunchentoot:easy-acceptor) request)
  (let* ((just-url (car (cl-ppcre:split "\\?" (hunchentoot:request-uri* request)))))
    (if (cl-ppcre:scan "^/auth-" just-url)
      (hunchentoot:redirect "/login")
      (call-next-method))))

(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (login :uri "/login") ()
  (with-html-output (*standard-output* nil :prologue t)
    (:html
     (:body
      (dolist (post (hunchentoot:post-parameters*))
    (format t "<div>~A ~A</div>" (car post) (cadr post)))))))
```

would work, but /login page fails to show anything. I guess the problem is that one cannot redirect with post data, as suggested by [the link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577011/redirect-with-post-parameters-in-mvc-4-for-payment-gateway-integration).

My previous attempt was to create a function, which saved the url ( with get parameters) in a hidden input, letting the user sign in, and then redirecting to the saved url. This looked very similar to the [2nd suggestion of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735/664404), and works for me. It's just that I can't DRY it.

I wonder if this can be done more simply using an around method and simply adding a "auth-" in front of any link.

Two more points:

- I guess I may dump the whole form to the session instead of post'ing them like [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get), but I don't want to keep track of cookies. What if the user decides to give up and all the values remain in the session?
- I prefer never to rely on http status code 307 [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133540/how-to-redirect-with-post-and-not-with-get-c-sharp).
- Lastly, I don't want to try frameworks like restas or caveman, because I want to learn lisp and fit in. I'm sure this problem had been solved many times by many people. In the past I built some stuff with rails. I was like a script kiddie until I learned enough ruby to see things the way they are.

## EDIT

Instead of `(hunchentoot:redirect "/login")`, I also tried `(drakma:http-request "http://127.0.0.1:4242/login" :method :post :parameters (hunchentoot:post-parameters* request))`, which failed with "ERROR MESSAGE 200". By the way, I don't know if trying to use drakma for this problem is an overkill or not.

Thank you for reading till the end.